# Password protected partitions on mac os x

Tags: macos, security, partition

I have two partitions first is primary with os x installed and second is empty, I want to password protect this second partition so when I double click it must ask for password and then tell me read write files.

I searched on internet but mostly people saying create a disk image apple encryption and you have password protected folder but I simply wants a password protected partition which ask for password who ever assess it.

Please tell me is there any benefit of creating standard user account sudo command can bypass it.

Comment: Based on your comments below you might need something else than a password-protected partition/image. Can you describe a bit more in detail which real-world problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @patrix Last week my mac mini HDD crashed, the only data I was able to recover which was on second partition, I recovered it through ubuntu live and using command line I bypass the permissions and copy data into my usb. Now I installed new HDD in mac mini and afraid if similar happen again I dont want to loose data any more. So now I have one admin account and three standard user account, me and my family use standard account. Now I want my second partition password protected not encrypted(because this will not recover from ubuntu).

Comment: @patrix So me and my family can save data on second partition which must be password protected, If any friend or any one try to access they must not enter or delete data in that protected partition.

Answer (score 2):

simply format the second partion as *Mac OS journaled encrypted* via Disk Utility

Comment: this is a good way but in case of HDD crash it will be impossible to recover the data. Last Week my HDD crashed and  I was able to recover only that data which was on my second partition. I recovered that data using ubuntu live usb and terminal commands to copy data into another usb drive.

Comment: Encrypted data is difficult (or even impossible) to recover anyway, exactly because it is encrypted. If recoverability is important to you, please edit/amend your question to avoid getting answers which don't fulfill your needs.

Comment: @SweetJenny that is a totally different problem. If you had a backup like Time Machine, you wouldn’t have this problem. I would still recommend, to make a single partition on your drive, maybe setup File Vault. Than use an external drive for Time Machine, if you really feel uncomfortable use 2 external for 2 separate backups. If you have files, which should be hard to access, use a encrypted sparsebundle. Did you replace the hard drive in your mini?

Comment: @SebastianSemmler yes i replaced the HDD

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve the problem on OS X actually *is* to create an encrypted disk image and put that on the second partition. This gives you all the benefits you'll get from an encrypted partition and works without additional software.

Alternatively you may want to look at [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org) which offers partition-level encryption (among others) and also works cross-plattform. It's a bit more difficult to configure/use but there are some good tutorials on the site.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I tried what you suggest in your answer but that image can be deleted for another standard user account. I want a partition with out encryption, when any user try to access it, password window pops.

Comment: Any user who knows the password is able to mount/access an encrypted disk image.

Comment: I created an encrypted image in second partition, then I login from another standard user account and try to delete the disk image that I created from my account and that disk image got delete without any password or any thing, means its not the secure option I can only protect my data for reading only but any one can delete it. Please can you tell me how to handle this situation.